# Term for intentionally blanking or blurring parts of images or videos

Tags: single-word-requests

Names or other sensitive information in an official document, or in a previously secret document now made public, are often deleted to protect the privacy of the individuals. It's usually done visibly, with the parts of the text painted over by a thick black line, or by blurring it. I know this practice is called "redacting", even if the word has a different original meaning. I often see "[redacted]" written over a removed part of text.

However, what is the term used if parts of images or videos are hidden. For example, a face of a person in an interview is pixelated to keep viewers from recognizing the person. A technical drawing which might end up in a video is pixelated to keep people from stealing it. A license plate of a car is pixelated, or painted black, etc. Is the word [redacted] used in this case? **I'm looking for a single word or a short phrase to *print across* a part of an image or video which is blanked, blurred, or pixelated intentionally** to keep people from discovering any sensitive information. The point is for viewers to recognize that it's not a mistake, but intentional.

"Censored" would be an alternative, but I don't think it fits this situation, as that word is often used for the purpose of hiding details people might find shocking, embarrassing or taboo.

Comment: Concealed, protected, screened, blocked? If an image is pixelated it's hardly accidental, people are aware of the underlying motivation for such instances.

Comment: I'm inclined to suggest _"altered"_. While it may be too broad for describing each of your scenarios, you could use terms like "visually altered" for the corresponding situation.

Comment: BTW here's a phone game, of all things, on the topic! https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/blackbar/id672002602

Comment: How about "elided"?

Comment: I think the word you yourself use, *pixelated,* would be apt, though I suppose there is some slight danger that it would be taken as implying that the person whose face is thus obscured is tipsy. ("You better stop drinking--you're getting all blurry!")

Comment: "Fig-leafing"..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on audience and if they need to understand the reason. It also depends on the reason for hiding a part of an image.

Could be: Intentionally Removed or Obscured.

Or use: 
Restricted.

Comment: Good suggestions, I like "Intentionally Removed".  "Altered" by dark knight is also good.   I really think **Restricted** is probably best, since you want short.  Don't forget simply **Secret** (if that has the right feel).  And finally. In actual government documents, the exact answer is simply **Classified**.

Answer (score 1):

I might be inclined to use the word "Redacted" or "Obfuscated".  Redacted actually refers to text not images.  Obfuscated is probably the better term.  Perhaps you could coin the term, "Digitally Obfuscated".  Of course that is two words and you wanted just one.

Answer (score 0):

How about *expunged?* I have seen it used in similar ways, i. e., printed across a section of a image or piece of text censored for secrecy.